# Get IP address in Grails

Tags: grails, ip-address

I know similar questions have been asked, but all has been asked some time ago so I will start a new thread.

I'm trying to get the ip address in grails, using this:

```
def String ipAddress ;

ipAddress = request.getHeader("Client-IP")

if (ipAddress == "")
request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For")

if (ipAddress == "")
request.getRemoteAddr()
```

If I use any of the request methods in isolation it works fine, however the second time I access a request method I get a Java hashmap error, e.g:

```
if this map contains a mapping from a key
* {@code k} to a value {@code v} such that {@code (key==null ? k==null :
* key.equals(k))}, then this method returns {@code v}; otherwise
* it returns {@code null}.  (There can be at most one such mapping.)
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `request.remoteHost` ?

Comment: How did you fix this error: No such property: request?  How do you import the request package/dependency?  googling this error did not help.

Comment: The code is doesnt seem right, def String should be def or String, and you should assign the variables ipAddress = request.get  ...

Answer (score 2):

Marius, I took your code made a few small changes, put it in a controller action and get the output:

```
null
null
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
```

The code:

```
        def ipAddress = request.getHeader("Client-IP")
        log.info ipAddress
        if (!ipAddress)
            log.info request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For")

        if (!ipAddress)
            log.info request.remoteAddr
```

I hope the changes are self explanatory?

Comment: Hi Steve Thanks for your prompt response. I've tried the code you provided, without success. It does not crash, but when accessing the request object the second time, (When in debug mode) it goes off to the Reference.jave file and then skips the rest of the code. I'm using Grails 2.01.

Comment: Hmmm where are you running this from?  A controller etc?  also try cleaning your build sometimes gets rid of "wierdness"

Comment: Any Idea how I fix this: "No such property: request"

Comment: @JohnLittle, I suggest creating a new question with as much relevant detail as possible, cheers.

Comment: Any idea how you get an normal (v4?) ip?

Comment: Use request.remoteHost

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to update code to the next:

```
def ipAddress = request.getHeader("Client-IP")
    log.info ipAddress
    if (!ipAddress){
        ipAddress=request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For")
        log.info "Used X-Forwarded-For header: $ipAddress"
    }
    if (!ipAddress){
        ipAddress=request.remoteAddr
        log.info "Used RemoteAddr attribute: $ipAddress"
    }
```

Otherwise the last condition will lead to incorrect behavior.